# Why is Drupal 6 returning Epoch date?

Tags: php, apache, solr, drupal-6

Whenever I input a standard search inside of a search box, majority (if not all) returned results appears in epoch time (DEC 31 1969), needless to say we don't have this date inside of our content.

our environment is using: php-5.3.3 (RHEL6), apache-solr-1.4.1 and apachesolr-6.x-2.0-beta2.

```
 # drush -r /var/www/html/current/ -l XXX.XXX.XXX pm-list | grep -iE '(?)solr(?)'
Apache Solr             Apache Solr comment search                          Module  Not installed  6.x-2.0-beta2
                         (apachesolr_commentsearch)                                                              
Apache Solr             Apache Solr Date (apachesolr_date)                  Module  Not installed  6.x-2.0-beta2
Apache Solr             Apache Solr Exclude (apachesolr_exclude)            Module  Enabled        6.x-1.0      
Apache Solr             Apache Solr framework (apachesolr)                  Module  Enabled        6.x-2.0-beta2
Apache Solr             Apache Solr image module integration                Module  Not installed  6.x-2.0-beta2
                         (apachesolr_image)                                                                      
Apache Solr             Apache Solr node access (apachesolr_nodeaccess)     Module  Disabled       6.x-2.0-beta2
Apache Solr             Apache Solr Organic Groups (apachesolr_og)          Module  Not installed  6.x-2.0-beta2
Apache Solr             Apache Solr search (apachesolr_search)              Module  Enabled        6.x-2.0-beta2
UFT                     UFT SOLR (uft_solr)                                 Module  Enabled                     
#
```

Also hooked same SOLR instance (using same module and everything) to another environment (biggest difference is running on RHEL5 instead of RHEL6 and running PHP-5.2.17 instead of PHP-5.3.3.) and I'm NOT getting DEC 31, 1969

Comment: What kind of schema.xml are you using on the solr core? What types of node fields are you trying to index as dates? Or are you trying to get just the updated and created dates?

Comment: After speaking with the tech guys, they tell me they are using the schema.xml that comes with SOLR core. As to your second question: both custom fields (like event date) as well as updated and create dates. It does not matter all dates are rendered as Dec., 31, 1969.

Comment: For the apachesolr module to work properly, you should use (or modify to your needs) the schema.xml provided with the module. Is this the situation on the RHEL5 machine too, or has Solr been configured 'properly' there?